# exception stop read files python

Tags: python, exception

I'm trying to control exceptions when reading files, but I have a problem. I'm new to Python, and I am not yet able to control how I can catch an exception and still continue reading text from the files I am accessing. This is my code:

```
import errno
import sys

class Read:
    #FIXME do immutables this 2 const
    ROUTE = "d:\Profiles\user\Desktop\\"
    EXT = ".txt"

    def setFileReaded(self, fileToRead):
        content = ""
        try:
            infile = open(self.ROUTE+fileToRead+self.EXT)
        except FileNotFoundError as error:
            if error.errno == errno.ENOENT:
                print ("File not found, please check the name and try again")
            else:
                raise
            sys.exit()
        with infile:
            content = infile.read()
            infile.close()

        return content
```

And from another class I tell it:

```
read = Read()
print(read.setFileReaded("verbs"))
print(read.setFileReaded("object"))
print(read.setFileReaded("sites"))
print(read.setFileReaded("texts"))
```

Buy only print this one:

```
turn on
connect
plug
File not found, please check the name and try again
```

And no continue with the next files. How can the program still reading all files?

Comment: Do not call `sys.exit()` if you do not want your program to exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little difficult to understand exactly what you're asking here, but I'll try and provide some pointers.

`sys.exit()` will terminate the Python script gracefully. In your code, this is called when the `FileNotFoundError` exception is caught. Nothing further will be ran after this, because your script will terminate. So none of the other files will be read.

Another thing to point out is that you close the file after reading it, which is **not needed** when you open it like this:

`with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    content = f.read()`

The file will be closed automatically after the `with` block.